# after upgrade, can't edit Contact Details fields (Custom Addressee and de-selected subtypes errors)

Tags: contacts, error, contact-types

I've just updated a Joomla 2.5.28 site from an older version of CiviCRM (4.4) to the latest 4.7.29.  Now I can't edit any of the fields under the "Contact Details" pane for existing records.

There are two errors:

1. When editing these fields for contacts that have custom subtypes, a popup appears saying "One or more contact subtypes have been de-selected from the list for this contact. Any custom data associated with de-selected subtype will be removed as long as the contact does not have a contact subtype still selected. Click OK to proceed, or Cancel to review your changes before saving."
2. For all contacts (including custom subtypes from item 1 above), saving doesn't work and throws this error:  "Custom Addressee is a required field if Addressee is of type Customized."

It's also interesting that I can create NEW records of contact subtypes, but get the errors again if I try to update the Contact Details of the new record.

I found this post ([Why after importing contact records were Addressee field values set to "Customized" for records where Custom Addressee had a null value?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4277/why-after-importing-contact-records-were-addressee-field-values-set-to-customize)) which seems to address issue #1, but I'm a bit stumped as to issue #2.  And I didn't want to try the correction suggested in this post until I knew if the two issues could be related.

Site details:
Joomla 2.5.28
CiviCRM 4.7.29

Comment: Crap. Just noticed I made a mistake in my first post -- the last paragraph should say that the post addresses item #2, and #1 has me stumped :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel this issue is documented  and fixed at [CRM-21180](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21180). You can try by applying [patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11364) or wait for 4.7.30 release.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Pradeep. Yes that seems to address issue #2, but not issue #1?

Comment: I feel it does please try

Comment: Oh ok, will do so.

Comment: I'm not having much success. I'll admit I'm not sure exactly what procedure I need to follow to apply the patch :-/  I've tried updating just the 11 files in the patch, and I've tried updating the whole codebase.  Both break my 4.7.29 installation. Are there any guides you could point me to?

Comment: Ooops, I should have searched first, then posted after :-) https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4622/how-do-i-apply-a-patch-supplied-in-the-issue-queue-via-git

Comment: OK, so I've applied the patch.  It seems to have fixed problem 2, but NOT problem 1.

I can make and save changes to records with Contact Subtypes, but first I see the "Contact Subtype" error as described above. If I click "OK" to ignore the warning, the record saves without complaining about custom addressees -- but all the custom subtype data is lost. 

So as I feared, the patch does address the custom addressee issue, but not this contact subtype problem.

Other ideas?

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer, because it did solve my question about the Custom Addressee issue. But since it seems these two issues aren't in fact related, I'm going to open a new question with just the Contact Subtype error. thanks again for your help here!